# Sine and Cosine Functions

Tags: time, velocity, differentiation, calculus, displacement

So long story short, We were given a windmill to experiment with and a sensor could sense the Voltage produced and graph it concerning time. We decided to make a sine wave out of the positive and negative Voltages produced.
*This was just done by alternating the direction (clockwise for +ve V and anti-clockwise for -ve V) rotation of the blades.*
So I thought of it a different way. Instead of Voltage and time, I thought of it as displacement and time.
In a Displacement time graph, the slope is the *velocity* of the object.
Since a sinewave is not a linear function, to find the slope I had to find the derivative of the function.

$$F(x) = \sin(x) \\ 
F'(x) = \cos(x)$$

#### how I derived here:

$$y = \ mx+b \\$$
since the sine wave starts at 0 the y-intercept would be 0 and b = 0.
distance is the y-axis and time is the x-axis.
$$y = \ mx \\
displacement (y) = velocity * time(x) \\ 
velocity = m (slope) \\
$$
the slope of a curved line is the derivative.

Since the slope was cos(x), the velocity of the graph should also be cos(x)

When I put this in a graph I did not get what I expected to get rather a weird graph.

please guide me on what I did wrong.
I am in grade 9 and know little calculus, which I used in this problem. I am happy to know if any alternative methods of tackling the problem and am open to suggestions

Just a random question I was curious about

[image: The weird graph i got]

Comment: Help us out by adding a bit more information.  How did you alternate the direction of rotation?  Do you expect that the rotation speed would vary sinusoidally?   What did you graph?  What vs. what?   What about its appearance is weird?

Comment: @garyp the way we did it doesn't really matter in this case we were just trying to make a sinewave. The positive Voltage happened when it was spun clockwise and the negative when anti-clockwise. And yes, the rotation speed would also vary in the form of a sine wave.      For the graph. The first time we graphed Voltage vs Time. What I thought of was displacement vs time.  I will attach the graph to the question momentarily.

Comment: The derivative is wrong.... you are plotting $x \cos x$, which is not the derivative of $\sin(x)$

Comment: pro tip: note that $\sin(x)$ is a _odd_ function, meaning $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$, so it flips sign when reflected about the $y$-axis. The derivative should then be an _even_ function (which satisfies:  $g(-x) = g(x)$, that is: the function is unchanged by reflection about the y-axis). These are so-called sanity checks (Stanford U notwithstanding) that you can apply to your work and detect mistakes.

Comment: @JEB thank you for explaining that. How do I fix this then? any ideas on how I can make it better??? I was thinking of it in class and at lunchtime. After all I am in grade nine so I donna a lot of stuff

Comment: maybe I'm just dumb idk

Comment: Look at what @JEB said: derivative of sin(x) with respect to x is not x cox(x), it is cos(x).

Comment: so does that mean the velocity is just cos(x) ? and changes with cosine

Comment: @grade9boi Yes.  If you're new to calc, learn the chain rule: $[f(g(x))]' = f'(g(x))g'(x)$, which is trivially applied here with $f(x) = \sin x$, $f'(x) = \cos x$, $g(x)=x$, $g'(x)=1$. Ofc with real data, you will have $g(x) = 2\pi\nu x + \phi$ here $\nu$ is the frequency in cycles per unit $x$, and $\phi$ is the phase of the oscillation at $x=0$.

Comment: thank you !!! Will learn more Calc and physics more in the comming moths Thank you all for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are after.

Assume the blade rotates in a circle of radius R.  The location of the tip of the blade in Cartesian coordinates is a vector $\vec l = Rcos(\theta) \hat x + Rsin(\theta)\hat y$ where $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ are unit vectors in the horizontal and vertical directions.  The velocity vector in Cartesian coordinates is $\vec v = {d\vec l \over dt} =-Rsin(\theta){d\theta \over dt}\hat x \enspace + \enspace Rcos(\theta){d\theta \over dt}\hat y = -Rsin(\theta)\omega\hat x \enspace + \enspace Rcos(\theta)\omega\hat y$ where $\omega = {d\theta \over dt}$ is the angular speed of rotation.

You can also express $\vec l$ and $\vec v$ in polar coordinates. $\vec l = R\hat n$ where $\hat n$ is a unit vector in the radial $r$ direction. $\vec v = R \omega \hat p$ where $\hat p$ is a unit vector in the angular $\theta $ direction.

Look up uniform circular motion on the web or in a basic physics textbook.

Comment: thank you! will learn more about this! Will learn more Calc and physics more in the coming moths Thank you for you help!

Comment: just a question @John Darby  how to we mark questions done (reference to GitHub)

Comment: Click on the up arrow by the answer you accept.

Comment: it tells me I need 15 reputation to do that and I have none so I clicked the check mark